# Change navbar color on scroll and screen width

Tags: javascript

I'm building my first website, and I want to have the navbar transparent on screen sizes over 992px and when you scroll below 400px the color changes to black. On screen sizes under 992px I want the navbar to always be black. My JS currently works the way I want for screen sizes over 992px but It's showing transparent on screen sizes under 992px where I want it to be black.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll < 400) && ($(window).width() <= 993){
        $('.navbar').css('background', 'transparent');
    } else{
        $('.navbar').css('background', 'rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle this with some CSS, using media queries is faster and more reliable than a javascript function that is being called on every single frame.

```
.navbar{
  background: transparent;
}

.blackBg{
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
}

/* Lets set the navbar as black on these smaller devices*/
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
   .navbar{
     background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) !important;
   }
 }
```

Next up in your script, lets only change the background to black when you scroll over 400, removing the window width requirement from the code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll < 400){
      $('.navbar').removeClass('blackBg');
    }else{
      $('.navbar').addClass('blackBg');
    }
});
```

Comment: It would cause less DOM thrashing if you were to add or remove a class that triggered the transparency/black background, rather than setting CSS on the element. You're already solving most of this with CSS, why not put it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media query and write a condition there